# Custom error message for password presence validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It seems like this should be straightforward. When signing up new users, I want custom errors for blank user names and passwords. It worked fine for the user name:

```
validates :name, presence: { message: "Please enter a name." },

                      length: { maximum: 50, 
                      message: "Please enter a name shorter than 50 characters"}
```

When the field is blank, it gives the "Please enter a name." error.

I the same thing for the password:

```
 has_secure_password
     validates :password, presence: { message: "Please enter a password." }, 
                          length: { minimum: 8,
                             message: "Please choose a password with at least 8 \
                             characters."}
```

The minimum length message works fine. But if I submit with an empty password, I get the default "can't be blank" message.

Comment: Try removing `has_secure_password` and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

has_secure_password validations: false worked at first, but I had a problem when I made the edit user profile page. It assumes the user might not enter a password. So it depends on the validations in has_secure_password, which the answer above disables.

A better way is to edit config/local/en.yml:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        password: "Password"
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            password:
              blank: "Please enter a password."
```

Answer (score 3):

[`has_secure_password`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password) automatically adds some validations for you:

> Password must be present on creation
>
> Password length should be less than or equal to 72 characters
>
> Confirmation of password (using a password_confirmation attribute)

To prevent that, declare:

```
has_secure_password validations: false
```

And then you can add your own.

Comment: That works! I figured it must have had something to do with has_secure_password, and that was indeed the case.

Comment: I found a better way to do this modifying config\app\locals.en.yml